# Is it possible to call factory binded variable in deviceready?

Tags: angularjs

I have following code somewhere in my javascript:

```
var app = angular.module("App");
app.factory('rest', function($http) {
});
```

index.js:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    // How I am able to call rest here?
    var domElement = document.documentElement;
    angular.bootstrap(domElement, ["App"]);

    var $body = angular.element(document.body);
    var $rootScope = $body.scope().$root;
    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('initialized', 'initialized');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can register a `run` function to your module. So when you will bootstrap your module run will be executed and in the `run` you will be able to access the factory. Something like this:

```
// Code goes here
var app = angular.module("App");
app.factory('rest', function($http) {});

app.run(function(rest) {
  console.log('your rest factory', rest);
});

document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
  // How I am able to call rest here?
  var domElement = document.documentElement;
  angular.bootstrap(domElement, ["App"]);

  var $body = angular.element(document.body);
  var $rootScope = $body.scope().$root;
  $rootScope.$apply(function() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('initialized', 'initialized');
  });
});
```

Comment: It should work. What challenges your are facing. I would suggest to create a plunkr or fiddle to play with